# Expo Go app shows older project version iso newest

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-go

We had a project that was on Expo SDK 44, but we recently created a new version with the latest SDK 48. However when we trigger a production build it uses the SDK 48 and the build is successful, but when we open the Expo Go app it still shows the older SDK 44 project in stead of the latest with 48.

No idea what the issue is causing this.. we tried re-installing the app, but nothing.